# Wait for store to update data before using it. Rxjs/Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Hello I am using angular with rxjs and I need to figure out a way to wait for the store to update its data after an action is dispatched to it to do something with that data. Here is what my relevant code looks like so far in my `component.ts`

```
  ngOnInit() {
  //subscribe to the store, get data from it
   this.store.pipe(select(selectors.getDataSelector)).pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)).subscribe(x => {
      this.data$ = x;
    });
  }

  updateData() {
    this.store.dispatch(new actions.getDataAction());
    // this action hits the http request, and stores the data in the store which is fetched with getDataSelector

    // now i need to do some condition that says `if the data in the store has completed updating after the action then do something
    if() {
      // do something with this.data$
    }
  }
```

Comment: What's wrong with just waiting for the subscription to be called? It means the data has updated.

Comment: how would i do this in my `updateData` function? @Chrillewoodz

Comment: Well I wouldn't since that would mean that you need to have 2 subscriptions and you will create a mess. Just have another function like `onUpdated` where you can do the sideeffects. If you need to check after certain actions you could write your own dispatcher which you then subscribe to instead, would be an alternative solution.

Comment: alright sounds good. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As previously said I wouldn't react in the `updateData` function, but rather in a `tap` operator like so:

```
  ngOnInit() {

   // Don't pipe multiple times as you did before
   this.store.pipe(
     select(selectors.getDataSelector),
     takeUntil(this.destroy$),
     tap((data) => this.foo())
   )
   .subscribe((data) => {
     this.data$ = data;
   });
  }

  updateData() {
    this.store.dispatch(new actions.getDataAction());
  }

  foo() {
    // do side-effects
  }
```